# C# razor page to Vb.net razor for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor-pages

I want to convert this code into VB.NET razor.

```
<div>
    <ul class="pagination">
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <li class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
        <a asp-page="/Index" asp-route-currentpage="@i" class="page-link">@i</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried but doesnt work

```
  @For Each item In Model
  @For i = 1 To item.TotalPages
  <li Class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
  <a asp-page="/Index" asp-route-currentpage="@i" Class="page-link">@i</a>/li>
   i += 1
    Next
    Next
```

Can someone please help. Not worked with VB.NET Razor before

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: VB.NET is not supported in Razor for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Its for asp.net mvc vb.net

Comment: You have tagged the question as Razor Pages, and you are using a tag helper. Razor Pages (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/) is not MVC, and tag helpers (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers) belong to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I am used working with asp.net core but had to go back to vb.net razor for a project which I have never used. Can you help to write the for loop in vb.net syntax without the tag helper

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a tag helper to render your anchor. Tag helpers are only available in ASP.NET Core which doesn't provide support for VB.NET in Razor. If you are actually developing a .NET Framework app (MVC 5), you cannot use tag helpers but you can use VB Net:

```
@For Each item In Model
  @For i = 1 To item.TotalPages
      <li class="page-item @If(i = Model.CurrentPage, "active", "")">
      <a href="/?currentpage=@i" class="page-link">@i</a>/li>
   Next
Next
```

Comment: Kudos to all who can effortlessly read razor's syntax within syntax within syntax.